# How to have Gradle properly pull down transitive dependency with incorrect metadata?

Tags: gradle

I am attempting to set up a gradle.build file and I am having an issue with the following transitive dependency:

`org.glassfish.ha:ha-api:3.1.8`.

It appears the pom.xml specifies that the binary is in "hk2-jar" format which is in fact incorrect, as the binary is simply in "jar" format.  After doing a bit of research I came across the following:

[How should gradle handle “hk2-jar” dependencies?](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-should-gradle-handle-hk2-jar-dependencies/17524)

Unfortunately, this did not seem to work.  Reading a bit more through the documentation I found I should be able to simply do something like so:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'org.glassfish.ha:ha-api:3.1.8@jar'
}
```

This produced similarly incorrect results:

[image: Attempts to pull from the wrong URL]

As you can see, it attempts to actually pull down the following URL:

http://repo-url/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api@jar/3.1.8@jar.pom

Does anyone have any idea how I can properly pull the correct binary and exclude the incorrect dependency?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Just wanted to add that the original issue I encountered is the fact that when Gradle attempts to download the ha-api dependency from our internal Artifactory, 403 is returned as the hk2-jar file does not exist within our repository (only the jar does):

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not determine artifacts for org.glassfish.ha:ha-api:3.1.8
   > Could not get resource 'http://repo-url/artifactory/libs-release/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.8/ha-api-3.1.8.hk2-jar'.
      > Could not HEAD 'http://repo-url/artifactory/libs-release/org/glassfish/ha/ha-api/3.1.8/ha-api-3.1.8.hk2-jar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

Comment: @tkruse, I have included the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem mostly when using Artifactory (not maven central / jcenter), for some reason.

Solution described at [Gradle forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-should-gradle-handle-hk2-jar-dependencies/17524)

For using the dependency in one project:

```
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
      all { DependencySubstitution dependency ->
        def requested = dependency.requested
        if (requested instanceof ModuleComponentSelector && requested.group == 'org.glassfish.ha' && requested.name == 'ha-api') {
          dependency.useTarget "org.glassfish.ha:ha-ap:${requested.version}@jar"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

For changing the transitive dependency in library projects (so other projects depending on this won't have to do the above):

```
publications {
    foo(MavenPublication) {
        pom.withXml {
           def dependency = asNode().dependencies.dependency.find {
              it.groupId.text() == 'org.glassfish.ha' && it.artifactId.text() == 'ha-api')
           }
           dependency.appendNode('type', 'jar')       
        } 
    }
}
```

It might be worth checking if this could also be done in Artifactory.